Unity freezes when I change anything
I am using 2022.3.51f1, macOS 15.2. If I reload compiles (like change any script). Or try to build, or maybe just try to close project it freezes and not even crashes. I always force quit the unity to close and every time I edit script I need to restart unity. The project isn't created in Mac, and there is some missing prefabs but I don't thing that some missing prefabs gonna cause the problem for freeze when touch anything (change any script), waiting for your suggestions.

Sounds like some editor script / asset post processor getting stuck in an infinite loop ..

1. Check if the Issue Occurs in All Projects:
Create a new project and see if the problem persists.
If it does, it’s likely a Unity or macOS compatibility issue. Try installing a clean, updated version of Unity or try updating your macOS.
Assuming it's a project specific issue...
2. Delete the Library Folder:
Close Unity, navigate to your project folder, and delete the Library folder.
Reopen the project, and Unity will rebuild the folder, which often resolves most issues.
3. Remove Plugins or all Editor Scripts/Utilities:
Some plugins or custom editor utilities might be running and causing these issues. Take a backup of the project and then remove all editor plugins and scripts in editor folder to find out.

I tryed deleting library and temp folders. Tried on different projects but no solution.
